# Using the 'performance' package in R, Error: Variable 'Component' is not in your data frame

Tags: r, performance, package, glm

The output for the "check_model()" function in the performance package is providing the error "Variable 'Component' is not in your data frame " . I am using a glm.nb model and some of my other models do not give this error. Has anyone ever experienced this issue? How did you fix it?

```
glm1 <- glm.nb(Total_bySp ~ Dist_WaterM + OpenWaterLC + Percent_Deciduous + 
  PastureLC + Temp_high , data=Haem)
summary(glm1)
```

where all variables are numbers

why does this error occur?

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Interestingly, this error also appears in the documentation of `see` for "Plot method for multicollinearity checks"
https://easystats.github.io/see/reference/plot.see_check_collinearity.html
and in the `Performance` package examples for "Check for multicollinearity of model terms" https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/check_collinearity.html 
perhaps it is more of a warning than an error. I got this error as well and the plots still display properly.

Comment: Something has changed in either check_model() or a dependency or something - code that worked previously produces this warning and no output. A work-around that worked for me was to plot the check_model object, so plot(check_model(glm1)) for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the authors, "It's not a bug, just a misleading warning/message".

It was fixed back in January. You can install the dev version with:

```
install.packages("easystats")
easystats::install_latest(force = TRUE)
```

See: https://github.com/easystats/performance/issues/545